# XMLHTTP Request post data hangs

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to create an AJAX call with the post method, and can't get it to work right. The script hangs at the processing stage (readyState does not go on to 4). 
I'd appreciate it if someone could enlighten me on the issue here. I've looked at a couple of tutorials, and it seems that my code -should- work.

```js
function newRequestPost(url, post, threadid, cfunc) {
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 var params = "post="+post+"&threadid="+threadid;
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc;
 xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send(params);
}

function openModalPreview(threadid) {
 var post = document.getElementById("post_txt").value;
 newRequestPost("url", post, threadid, function() {
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 1) {
   document.getElementById("that_which_lies_in_the_modal").innerHTML = "Loading...";
  }
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 2) {
   document.getElementById("that_which_lies_in_the_modal").innerHTML = "Received";
  }
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 3) {
   document.getElementById("that_which_lies_in_the_modal").innerHTML = "Processing...";
  }
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
   document.getElementById("that_which_lies_in_the_modal").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: "readyState does not go on to 4" — What does it do? How are you testing that it reaches `4`? What if it does reach `4` by the status is not `200`? Are they errors in your JS console?  What does the Net tab tell you about the request?

Comment: Basically I ran the script and it last updated the element with the code in the if readyState 3 brackets. Did some more testing just now. It does reach 4, but status is not 200. It's not 404 either though. If I take out the status condition I get an error saying that the requested action is not allowed. Seems like a codeigniter issue.

Comment: I solved the issue. Thanks for your comment! It got me to figure things out after all.